# Как получить данные из нескольких элементов списка?

Tags: python, css, scrapy

Есть код, собирающий некоторые данные из первого элемента первого списка на сайте https://pravo.ru/news/239550/
Однако, мне нужно получить данные всех элементов всех списков.
Тут, наверное, нужен цикл, но лично у меня его встроить не получилось :(
Поэтому ради заботы о ваших глазах оставляю тут рабочую версию кода, надеясь на вашу помощь.

```
import scrapy

class Bruslispider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'imposters'
    start_urls = ['https://pravo.ru/news/239550/']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield{
            'name':response.css('ul.default li a::text').get(),
            'descript':response.css('ul.default li::text').get(),
            'linkPruf':response.css('ul.default li a::attr(href)').get()

        }
```

Еще раз о целях данного вопроса: прошу помочь внедрить в код цикл так, чтобы спарсить все элементы всех списков

Comment: А что выдаёт `response.css('ul.default li a::text').get()` - один элемент или список? Может вам нужно `zip` от этих трёх штук сделать, чтобы перебирать параллельно. Но я вообще не уверен, что всё получится, лучше блоки обрабатывать, а не так вот по отдельности каждую сущность, они могут рассинхронизироваться.

Comment: response.css('ul.default li a::text').get() , как и все строки выдают корректные данные, но лишь 1 элемент. Конкретно эта строка выводит название компании. Спасибо за совет с zip, изучу как это можно применить. Я бы и не прочь разрабатывать блоки, но вся нужная информация представлена в списках